# Tkinter toolbar not showing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-menu

Note: Ive searched for this but find information about java and android. That's not what I need.

I am really new to Tkinter and I am coding in Python 3. I have searched the normal web to look at examples and my code looks correct but doesn't give me the result I'm going for.

```
root=Tk()
root.title("You go boy!!")
root.iconbitmap(Path())


#Menu
menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

subMenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New Project",command=donothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="Options",command=donothing)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Close Window",command=root.quit)

editMenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit",menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Undo",command=donothing)
editMenu.add_command(label="Cut",command=donothing)
editMenu.add_command(label="Copy",command=donothing)

#Toolbar

tlbar = Frame(root,bg="yellow")
Button1 = Button(tlbar, text="Copy", command=donothing)
Button2 = Button(tlbar, text="Cut", command=donothing)
Button3 = Button(tlbar, text="Print", command=donothing)
Button1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
Button2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
Button3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
tlbar.pack(side=TOP)

root.mainloop()
```

My result is that the window loads with no errors but the toolbar does not generate. My IDE is Pycharm (although I dont believe thats the issue.)

All feedback is welcomed as I am trying to become better. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me.  Are you seeing the yellow background of the Frame at all?

Comment: @jasonharper, I dont see it at all. I wish  could send you a screenshot.

Comment: As written, this code won't run. It's missing an import statement or two, and you haven't defined `donothing`.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve the issue I restarted the IDE and rewrote the code. It then worked like normal. Thank you all for assisting me with this issue.